# UK Tax: Filling in a HMRC P85 Form - Leaving the UK

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

I'm filling in the [online P85 form](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/income-tax-leaving-the-uk-getting-your-tax-right-p85) as I recently moved back to Australia permanently but I'm but I'm stuck on two questions on page 2:

[image: page 2 of the P85]

I will not be receiving any income from the UK after I leave. However, I will be working in Australia. Should my answers be:

1. No
2. Yes

Selecting Yes for the second question opens up a lot more questions about the employment.

The form seems poorly designed given that the second question is under that section.

Anyway, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes. There is no other reason to say no. What did you say for `Will you continue to have your salary paid from the UK?`

Comment: I said "No". My work in Australia will be paid by an Australian-based employer.

Answer (score 8):

If you are moving back to Australia permanently and you are an Australian resident say "No" to both questions. The 2nd question is really aimed at UK residents working abroad, but still receiving an income from UK. You are right it's not very clear, but the clue is in the title "Income you get from the UK after you leave" as you are being payed by Australian-based employer it does not apply to you.